# Extract youtube video's title in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to extract youtube video's titles but nothing works. I'm working on a chrome extension and i need to export the video's title.

Here's my code so far:

```
// Function to extract the song information from the YouTube page
function extractSongInfo() {
    // Extract the video title from the YouTube page's DOM
    const titleElement = document.querySelector('.title.ytd-video-primary-info-renderer');
    const videoTitle = titleElement ? titleElement.innerText : '';

    // Extract the artist information from the YouTube page's DOM
    const artistElement = document.querySelector('.ytp-subtitles-button');
    const artist = artistElement ? artistElement.getAttribute('aria-label') : '';

    // Send the song information to the background script
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'SONG_INFO', title: videoTitle, artist });
}

// Call the function to extract song information
extractSongInfo();
```

I tried the code below

Comment: A quick look showed that `document.querySelector('#title yt-formatted-string').innerText` works. Not sure if this will work in Chrome extensions though.

Comment: For the title, try `document.querySelector('div#title yt-formatted-string');`. Can you try it?

Comment: Please use `MutationObserver` to access dynamically generated content.

Answer (score 0):

iniside youtube video page :

this is the video description:
`document.querySelector('#description-inline-expander').innerText`

and the title is :
`document.querySelector('#below #title h1').innerText`

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it as follows:

```
document.title
```

And replace  "- YouTube" from it.